# How to put "et al" not in italics with nature style

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a document in Overleaf. For the bibliography, I am using:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=nature,
maxcitenames=2,
uniquelist=false,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

However, I need the "et al." to appear not in italics. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `biblatex-nature` package, in its `nature.bbx` file, defines the  `name:andothers` macro (note the use of `\mkbibemph`):

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    }
    {
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
      \andothersdelim
      \mkbibemph{\bibstring{andothers}}%
    }
    {}%
}
```

In your preamble, after `biblatex`, you can redefine the `name:andothers` macro without `mkbibemph`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    }
    {
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
      \andothersdelim
      \bibstring{andothers}%
    }
    {}%
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!